# Timezone incorrect

Tags: 16.04, ntp, timezone

I've freshly installed a 16.04 instance in VMWare, which sadly automatically configures the installation process for me. Now I try to repair what it has broken.

One of the steps is to get ntp to work correctly. I installed ntp, then checked whether the ubuntu pools are in `/etc/ntp.conf`, then set my location via `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, then rebooted.

Now my system thinks UTC is actually the time that would be correct in my local time zone. Then additionally it applies the time zone, which results in a very incorrect time. Shouldn't the ntp pools tell it what the UTC time is? How to debug this?

Comment: What is your host? is your host using UTC or localtime?

Comment: @Ravexina local time zone and it shows the time correctly.

Comment: Run:  `timedatectl set-local-rtc true`, then set the correct time manually or using ntp. then it should be okay.